# How to extract substring in Fish shell?

Tags: substring, fish, parameter-expansion

I got the following variable:

```
set location "America/New_York"
```

and want to display only the part before the `/` (slash) **using `fish` shell syntax**.

#### Expected result

> America

#### Bash equivalent

Using bash, I was simply using a parameter expansion:

```
location="America/New_York"
echo ${location##*/}"
```

### Question

How do I do that in a `fish`-way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since fish 2.3.0, there's a builtin called `string` that has several subcommands including `replace`, so you'll be able to do

```
string replace -r "/.*" "" -- $location
```

or

```
set location (string split "/" -- $location)[1]
```

See http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#string.

Alternatively, external tools like `cut`, `sed` or `awk` all work as well.

Comment: What if we care about both return values? Storing them in a list works, but is there a way to store them into more specific vars straight away? E.g. `set a, b (string split / foo/bar)`

Comment: maybe you could add a link to the docs, and find out/mention what's the first version that supports `string replace`?

Comment: 2.3 (which was released after that answer was written, so there were no docs to link to), http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#string.

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to use `cut` but, that look hackish:

```
set location "America/New_York"
echo $location|cut -d '/' -f1
```

> America

Comment: Part of the fish philosophy is to have as small a feature set as possible. fish does not do parameter expansion like bash with `${location%%/*}`.  This answer is the fish way. From the [Design document](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/design.html): "Everything that can be done in other shell languages should be possible to do in fish, though fish may rely on external commands in doing so."

Answer (score 2):

Use the field selector `-f` of `string split`

```
> string split / "America/New_York" -f1
America
```

and accordingly:

```
set location (string split / "America/New_York" -f1)
```

Sidenote: For the latter string involving multiple slashes, I don't know anything better than the cumbersome `-r -m1 -f2`:

```
> string split / "foo/bar/America/New_York" -r -m1 -f2
New_York
```